# Congratulations, @rfusca! Welcome our new Moderator!

Tags: discussion, election

Well, our recent moderator election is *finally over!*

It was a rather long process, and one which I believe many of us were worried would end without any nominees at all! :o First things first, I think we need to offer a round of applause to the runner up, [MikeW](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4191/mikew). He had the guts and bravery to step up to the plate after several days of eerie quiet. If it wasn't for him, our race may never have gotten off the ground! So thank you, Mike! It takes a certain amount of dedication to freely offer up some of your personal time to a community like PhotoSE, and we're all appreciative. :)

Next up, its time to congratulate the winner of our election, and our new community servant, [rfusca](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1917/rfusca)! King of the chatroom, the man who is always there to greet you when you enter, help you when you have a question, offer quality chat and banter any time of the day (or night, as is often the case) and salute you when you sign off, he is an incredibly valued member of our community. He's been here since the beginning, and has participated in both the main site and meta extensively. He has his hands quite full with a growing family, and its most generous for him to offer more time to our community as our fourth moderator. We are grateful for your dedication, and welcome your assistance in managing our growing forum.

### ***Congratulations, rfusca!***

Comment: Can we know who received how many votes? ;D ;D

Comment: @AnishaKaul The results are available for download from the election page at http://photo.stackexchange.com/election/2

Comment: Thanks @RowlandShaw I'll take a look.

Comment: @AnishaKaul - Here's a link to the results http://i.stack.imgur.com/GUAdg.png

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations rfusca!  Well deserved :)

Comment: Thanks Mike, it was great to run with you.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats as it is, indeed, very well earned.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, congratulations indeed. A great addition to the crew.

As for the nominees issue, well, there aren't any in our process, are there? It's more a "volunteers" thing, and I suppose I can understand that since there's a time commitment involved. I'm both an unreliable disabled guy *and* often incapable of completely trusting my own judgement because of the effects of my condition on my brain, so that rather left me out. I'll stay away from anything that could go either way—I'd rather let saner heads prevail, even if I don't quite agree.

But it would be nice, I think, if there were a means of making declinable nominations of people who would be great mods given the chance through some sort of back-door channel. (I don't know about the rest of you, but I was rather surprised that mattdm didn't step forward, given all of the work he puts into this site already. Would that have changed if he were given a nudge?)

Comment: I talked with @mattdm and purposefully delayed my nomination till I spoke with him.  He wasn't interested in an 'official' position.  I would not have ran if he choose to.  I far as I was concerned, the position was his if he wanted it.  He got that 'nudge' ;)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3340938#3340938

Comment: @rfusca Thanks for that. My connection barely supports the main site, and my attempts to get into chat have never gone well. And I would still have voted for you (I thought there was going to be more than one selected in the end) had you both been in the race.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of surprised me Matt didn't either. Having said that, it would appear that Matt has been pretty effective without the diamond, so I doubt that will change. Moderation does also bring a sense of obligation...

Comment: Also, he's got a high enough reputation that the difference isn't that big.

Answer (score 1):

That's excellent news - as such an active and helpful member already I thought he was a natural choice.